# jquery change fixed element text color with anchor points

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to change the color of the text within a fixed header, at the point when it scrolls over a particular div. I've got pretty much no jQuery knowledge, but have cobbled together a method using a specified pixel measurement, that when scrolled to, the said text color changes.
Here's the ***current jQuery code***:

```
$(document).ready (function () {
   $(window).scroll (function () {
    var sT = $(this).scrollTop();
        if (sT >= 400) {
            $('.header').addClass('change')
        }else {
            $('.header').removeClass('change')
        }
  });
});
```

What I really need is for the change to occur at an anchor point, so that it holds up across different devices sizes. Hope that makes sense?

Here's what I've got working in codepen:
http://codepen.io/danburrows/pen/ChFxi

hope someone can help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to compare the position of the div where you want to change the color of the text to the position of the scrollbar...

Here is the codepen : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/sgmaJ

You don't need to change much of your JQuery code.

Just change your `if` statement to this :

```
if (sT - $('.bottom').position().top > 0) {
    $('.header').addClass('change')
}else {
    $('.header').removeClass('change')
}
```

Comment: @user3590501 think you can mark this as correct if it is what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

You can reach it with this code:

```
$(document).ready (function () {
    $(window).scroll (function () {
        var sT = $(this).scrollTop();
            if (sT >= $('.bottom').offset().top) {
                $('.header').addClass('change')
            }else {
                $('.header').removeClass('change')
            }
    });
});
```

You have to search for the offset of the object you want.